# Use socket Connection as User Identity

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I´m creating a Java TCP socket server (java.net.Socket) using one thread for each client connection.
I would like to know if I can authenticate the user by his connection. or would it be a lack of security?

at the moment to verify if a thread connection can access a specific app resource, I`m verifying the identity like this:

```
public boolean Authenticate()
{
    return Thread.currentThread().getId() == this.userThread.getId();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

The connection it self is not a certain identity.
It is only communication and the underlying infrastructure to transport the data.
To validate a user you need to implement something that sends a unique identifier.

Threads are created at connection time and will change from connection to connection even if it is the same "user" connecting.

Securing the identity of a user is done at application layer (see [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)) while communication is done on various levels below.

To this you can add the encryption to make the communication secure.